# Android Cursor Init

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cursor

I have very strange problem that couldn't resolve so far.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 9, col 1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
```

I have searched the similar posts but still couldn't find any solution.

I have some data in `Sqlite` and when I'm trying to get it I have this `error`.

Here's my `code` of extracting `data`:

```
public static ArrayList<DetailsItemI> selectDetailsWithRecId(long recId) {
    int tabId;
    String tag, value;
    String selection = DBHelper.DETAILS_REC_ID + " = " + recId;
    Cursor c = db.query(DBHelper.DETAILS_TABLE, null, selection, null, null, null, DBHelper.DETAILS_TAB_ID + " ASC");
    ArrayList<DetailsItemI> list = new ArrayList<DetailsItemI>();
    DetailsItemI inputItem;

if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
            tabId = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.DETAILS_TAB_ID));
            tag = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.DETAILS_VIEW_PARAMETER));
            value = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.DETAILS_VALUE));

            inputItem = new DetailsItem(tabId, tag, value);
            list.add(inputItem);
    } while (c.moveToNext());
}
return list;
}
```

`Column` `count` in `cursor` is 4, so the problem shouldn't be in it. I think it's the `row` problem but have no idea why.

Thanks for help in Advance.

**Full StackTrace:**

```
06-30 13:39:17.763    1033-1033/ge.altasoft.datacollector E/CursorWindow﹕ Failed to read row 9, column 1 from a CursorWindow which has 9 rows, 4 columns.
06-30 13:39:17.768    1033-1033/ge.altasoft.datacollector E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ge.altasoft.datacollector/ge.altasoft.datacollector.DetailsActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 9, col 1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 9, col 1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
            at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetLong(Native Method)
            at android.database.CursorWindow.getLong(CursorWindow.java:511)
            at android.database.CursorWindow.getInt(CursorWindow.java:578)
            at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getInt(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:69)
            at ge.altasoft.database.DBManager.selectDetailsWithRecId(DBManager.java:358)
            at ge.altasoft.datacollector.DetailsActivity.fillTheData(DetailsActivity.java:278)
            at ge.altasoft.datacollector.DetailsActivity.initViews(DetailsActivity.java:71)
            at ge.altasoft.datacollector.DetailsActivity.onCreate(DetailsActivity.java:62)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5188)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**EDITED**

In the `app` I have lots of `fields` that should be filled. I save all of them as `strings`. Some of the `fields` are `Image` `Fields`, and I `save` those `images` as `Base64 Strings`.

On one `tab` I have 3 `Image` `Fields` and this `error` happens during extracting the third `image` `field`, but it only happens with 3 `specific image combination`. Have no Idea why.

Comment: what do you need selectDetailsWithRecId() method for?

Comment: Please post full stacktrace.

Comment: selectDetailsWithRecId() is for getting saved data.

Comment: @laalto I have added full stacktrace

Comment: you are most likely not using a SimpleCursorAdapter,  why?

Comment: Anything before the exception stacktrace (from the native sqlite layer)? Also a `static` method using member variables like `db` initialized elsewhere is a design smell but likely not related to this problem.

Comment: Ok, base64 image data in the cursor is likely the culprit. The data won't fit the cursor window (there would be some prior messages about that). Remove the base64 data from the database, or at least don't include those columns in the cursor selection.

Comment: But there isn't any message about Memory allocation besides it works quit well with more images in another data extraction method.